# Qual a forma correta de inserir um dado necessário em um construtor no PHP?

Tags: php, parâmetros, construtor

Como devo colocar os parâmetros dentro do parenteses do construtor?

Tentei da seguinte forma como vi em videos mas apresenta o seguinte erro:
OBS.: estou usando o terminal, estou usando o arquivo `criando.php;` para agilizar.

```
<?php

require 'Conta.php';

$novaConta= new Conta(cpf: '123.123.123-2', titular: 'David');

?>
```

Está apresentando o seguinte erro:

> Interactive shell
>
> php > require 'criando.php';
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' in C:\meuphp\atom\criando.php on line 6

A linha 6 mencionado acima é onde insiro os dados:

```
$novaConta= new Conta(cpf: '123.123.123-2', titular: 'David');
```

Na classe que o objeto recebe, o construtor esta da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

class Conta{

  private $cpf;
  private $titular;
  private $saldo;

  public function __construct(string $cpf, string $titular){
    $this->cpf=$cpf;
    $this->titular=$titular;
    $this->saldo=0;

  }
}

?>
```

A versão do meu PHP é a 7.4.

Como passar o valor, pois vi em vídeos e é dessa forma que eles passaram?

Comment: Aonde você viu esse recurso? em qual vídeo? pode postar junto com a pergunta?

Comment: Foi em um curso no Alura

Comment: mas, é em PHP ?

Comment: Sim, foi em um curso de PHP.

Comment: Então se tem que postar aqui isso, porque já aceitou de cara a resposta se a sua pergunta diz outra coisa? Porque a resposta que você aceitou é o normal de qualquer linguagem...

Comment: Não lembro de ter postado algum link do material de estudo, somente especifiquei onde foi, se não quer a resposta não pergunte.

Comment: Qual o link desse vídeo?

Comment: A pergunta diz vídeo suponhamos link então ficamos curioso pra saber onde viu isso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não pode colocar o nome do parâmetro. PHP não tem o mecanismo de argumentos nominados como outros linguagens tem.

Se viu isso em um vídeo de PHP, já é uma boa indicação que é uma fonte ruim, como grande parte do vídeos que existem na internet, principalmente sobre programação. Muita coisa é ensinada errada por aí, e o melhor que pode acontecer é dar um erro, quando não dá em geral a pessoa usará errado por resto da vida porque escolheu um fonte de estudo ruim.

Usando a forma posicional funciona, então só colocar os argumento para bater nas posições dos parâmetros do construtor:

```
$novaConta= new Conta('123.123.123-2', 'David');
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/Construing.php).

Comment: Agora deu certo, a forma posicional é de acordo com a declaração dentro do __construct né ?

Comment: @Medivh Exatamente.